# Login windows users from code

Tags: c++, windows, multiple-users

I'd like to get a list of windows users and log in the ones I want from c++ code.

I'm not asking for the code to do it, just recommendations of what API to use, if there's any or at least a first approach of how it could be done.

Comment: "_I'm not asking for the code to do it, just recommendations of what API to use_" And asking for API recommendations is off-topic on SO.

Comment: @Alg: That's not correct. The question is asking for first party API calls on Windows, not some 3rd party library recommendations. As such it isn't off-topic. Please see [help/on-topic].

Comment: @IInspectable 1) Windows supports many libraries, with, sometimes, overlapping functionality, which have their own APIs. 2) If the question asked specifically about WINAPI, I would agree with you, however, the question asked just "for recommendations of what API to use", which is, IMO, the same, as asking for library recommendations.

Comment: @Alg: Except, it isn't. It is asking for guidance on which APIs to use *from a fixed set of APIs* (the Windows API). That is distinctly different from asking for recommendations on 3rd party libraries, which are by virtue unbounded. That reason to close a question is there to prevent opinionated answers. If you want to close this question, do so because it is *"too broad"*.

Comment: @IInspectable Once again, this question didn't ask about Windows API. This question stated that it wanted to get a list of Windows users, and wanted recommendations on what API to use. Meaning: it wanted API that worked on Windows, but not necessarily being Windows API (WINAPI).

Comment: @Alg: You are making assumptions. If in doubt, ask for clarification. Don't just blindly vote based on your interpretation, unless it is unambiguously clear. You seemingly agree, that it isn't.

Comment: To be able to log those users in through code, you should have their passwords too.

Comment: @IInspectable Windows API (WINAPI) isn't mentioned anywhere in the question, and yet I am the one, that is making assumptions, that the question is not about Windows API?

Comment: @Alg: The question is tagged [tag:windows], and is asking for an API. Windows' API is the Windows API. It's not an irrational interpretation, that that's what the OP is asking for. If in doubt, leave a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: @IInspectable 1) I will repeat myself one more time: Sure, Windows' API is **one** of the APIs available **on** Windows. But the question is asking to recommend the API to use, which means, they aren't talking about a specific API, but about a general set of APIs, that Windows supports. If this question was tagged with [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) - it would be clear that this question is, specifically, about Windows API. 2) "_If in doubt_" There is no doubt. I explained my point of view several times already.

Comment: @Alg: Did you bother to read the [winapi tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/winapi/info)? It reads: *"The Windows API [...] is the core set of application programming **interfaces** available for the Microsoft Windows operating systems."* It says "interfaces", plural. So if you are asking about the API to use, that doesn't necessarily imply that you are looking for a 3rd party library. There is a crypto API, a windowing API, a multimedia API, a rendering API, and a long list of other APIs. The question could be interpreted either way.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I'm sorry if I didn't explain it well. I'm not asking for API recommendations. I came out with this task and I need to do it but I don't know how to because I don't know how windows users are managed. I just want a starting point for solving the problem but I don't want anyone to do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if something as specific as that but there several API and libraries you can try as for example this one `include Windows.h` and use the following syntaxis

```
BOOL WINAPI OpenProcessToken(
  _In_  HANDLE  ProcessHandle,
  _In_  DWORD   DesiredAccess,
  _Out_ PHANDLE TokenHandle
);
```

To check which access token is open.
Check the following link for more information on [Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/access-rights-for-access-token-objects)